# prefix calculator using stack in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, stack

i'm trying to make calculator with RPN (reverse polish notation) input method using stack in javascript.

`input : [1, 5, '+', 6, 3, '-', '/', 7, '*']`

1 is an operand, push to Stack.

5 is an operand, push to Stack.

'+' is an operator, pop 1 and 5, calculate them and push result to Stack.

6 is an operand, push to Stack.

3 is an operand, push to Stack.

'-' is an operator, pop 6 and 3, subtract them and push result to Stack.

'/' is an operator, pop 6 and 3, divided them and push result to Stack.

7 is an operand, push to Stack.

'*' is an operator, pop 2 and 7, multiply them and push result to Stack.

`output : [14]`

is there any other alternative to make my code more effective?

```
const x1 = x.push(1);
const x2 = x.push(5);
const x3 = x.push('+');

x.pop(1);
x.pop(5);
x.pop('+');
x.push(1+5);

const x4 = x.push(6);
const x5 = x.push(3);
const x6 = x.push('-');

x.pop(6);
x.pop(3);
x.pop('-');
x.push(6-3);

const x7 = x.push('/');
x.pop(6);
x.pop(3);
x.pop('/');
x.push(6/3);

const x8 = x.push(7);
const x9 = x.push('*');

x.pop(2);
x.pop(7);
x.pop('*');
x.push(2*7);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: A. This is postfix, not prefix. B. You should just be calling `x.pop()` with no parameter, and using the results from the pops. Also, you need to create add,subtract, multiply and divide functions that take two parameters each, rather than using +-*/ in your code

Comment: ah yes, my bad. that's postfix. ok will try it. thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take an object for all operators and check if the value of `input` is an operator, then perform the operation with the reversed popped values of the stack or push the value to the stack.

```js
const
    operators = {
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b,
        '/': (a, b) => a / b
    },
    input = [1, 5, '+', 6, 3, '-', '/', 7, '*'],
    stack = [];

input.forEach(value => {
    stack.push(value in operators
        ? operators[value](...stack.splice(-2))
        : value
    );
    console.log(...stack);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow this is a remarkably concise implementation! +1

Comment: so, we just pull out element from `input` and push it to new array `stack`. there's no need to use `.pop()` ?

Comment: yes, but `stack.splice(-2, 2)` delets the last two values of the stack and returns them in an array. this array is spreaded as parameters for the operation.